# Difference between hostip.info and ipinfo.io

Tags: api, geolocation

I am currently using the `hostip.info` service for geolocation (converting IP addresses of my users to their longitude/latitude). The service is responsive and accurate when it knows about the IP address. However, a lot of my users report that their IP addresses are not in the database.

I hate to lose the advantage of `hostip.info`, which allows users to update their info themselves, but I am considering switching to `ipinfo.io` service in hope it has a more comprehensive database.

Did anyone try the two services? Can you please tell me about which one worked better (more detection rate, more accuracy, better responsiveness, etc)?

The `hostip.info` sites reports 9,173,221 IP entries in their database. The `ipinfo.io` site does not say.

BTW, I am not interested in free LITE-databases, such as `MaxMind` or `ipinfodb.com` since they are not very accurate (unfortunately), neither am I looking for paid services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [www.ipv4.cf](http://www.ipv4.cf/)

> IPv4.cf is a free IP Lookup service for non-commercial use. Ipv4.cf
>   provides a public free REST API for doing a lot of Geotargeting or IP
>   Address Lookups through multiple response formats. It supports
>   multiple formats, include json, xml, csv, plain, png. And It supports
>   multiple languages.
>
> Read more: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/ipv4#ixzz2u1WXejzm

It has its geoloction database, and what is special is that it uses Google to correct its result.

Comment: this should be a comment, I do not think it is worthy of an answer